# Override style enforced within a .js

Tags: javascript, css, html

**Scenario:**

I'm dealing with an image map, and I'm trying to combine the use of 2 java-scripts, the first is this one: http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper Which easily enables the highlighting of the hovered target area.

And the second being this one: http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html
Which makes the whole image map scale, updating the coordinates based on the image size (which is fantastic).

The issue is within the first .js (mapper.js) which for obvious reasons, enforces that the target image can't scale with the browser, as the coordinates are static and having the image change size would make the image map completely wrong.

However the 2 should be able to work together as they both use the same standard image-map code, with the only addition being the application of a class to the image tag. The first js would just be able to read the coordinates as they updates, but they never updates as its stopping the image from scaling.

**Question**

Is it possibly to edit a .js or to overrisde the styling within a .js?

I've tried simply adding inline CSS, or "!Important", but doesn't work.

Comment: !important should work.. - inside your css. Js with that inline style forcing is annoying... But you can allways overwrite it with your own js :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can edit a js file to add styles to an HTML element.